# nvcomp: How do i get compressed buffer (or compressed buffer size)?

Tags: compression, buffer, nvidia

I would like to use nvidia nvcomp library to compress/uncompress images on GPU. I follow the high_level_quickstart_example and try to use high level api. In particular i'm facing with the decomp_compressed_with_manager_factory_example method. I am wondering if it is possible to achieve the compressed buffer (or the size of compressed buffer), in order to use it to save on disk (as binary raw data) or to send it on the network. In other words, i'm looking for documentation and/or examples which shows how to get compressed buffer after image compression procedure. Do i look at the right nvcomp example? If no, can you suggest me the right one?
Thank you in advance.
Kind regards.